# How to find value in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, range, vlookup

I have a list of values that I need to look up, but I was given ranges in another table eg: <0.1, 0.1-0.5, 0.5-1.0 ... with their corresponding value. I have tried the INDEX MATCH and used TEXT to change my list of values so that I can compare it to the range. However, each time I refresh, the result changes, probably because it's not an exact match. Can someone help me with better ways to do this? It seems to work fine at first, but it messes up my sorting every time I refresh, not sure if there's another way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your list of target ranges. One, as you have already found, they are text. Therefore they form an instruction for what you should program but can't be used directly. Secondly, they are logically wrong: What about the gap between 1.0 and 1.5? I presume that the last range should be ">1.0". This leads you to the following function.

```
=MATCH(A7,{100,1,0.5,0.1},-1)
```

The match, as specified by `-1`, looks for the first number which is larger or equal to the match item. Any number larger than 1 will be matched in the first range (100 - 1) but 1 itself will be matched by the second range (1 to 0.5). A number larger than 100 will throw an error, but you can insert any large number. This function will lead you to the formula below.

```
=INDEX({"d","c","b","a"},MATCH(A7,{100,1,0.5,0.1},-1))
```

This demonstrates the logical flaw in the construction of the ranges. The above formula can't return the correct result for 0.1. This can be done by the formula below which, however, can't return the correct result for 1.0

```
=INDEX({"a","b","c","d"},MATCH(A7,{0,0.1,0.5,1},1))
```

There are two ranges in these formulas. As explained, it's impossible to reference the range you have in column A of your example because it's text. But you might use column B directly if you convert the result of the MATCH function to an index row. `5 - MATCH()` would reverse the order, returning 1 in place of 4 and 4 in place of 1.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the jump, I didn't realize that when I made the example. Thank you!